# How to create a co-variance matrix from a correlation matrix and a volatility vector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have this correlation matrix in a dataframe `df_corr`:

```
ticker     CNP         F        GE      TSLA       WMT                                                  
CNP     1.000000  0.302712  0.408604  0.205812  0.289421
F       0.302712  1.000000  0.510077  0.302415  0.280815
GE      0.408604  0.510077  1.000000  0.288827  0.326106
TSLA    0.205812  0.302415  0.288827  1.000000  0.166978
WMT     0.289421  0.280815  0.326106  0.166978  1.000000
```

I have this volatility vector in a dataframe `df_vol`:

```
CNP       0.012789
F         0.014525
GE        0.011579
TSLA      0.026573
WMT       0.011369
```

I would like to have the co-variance matrix. I cannot use numpy cov in my real example because the volatility and the correlation are not coming from the same table.

Here are the expected results:

```
ticker     CNP        F        GE       TSLA       WMT    
CNP     0.000164  0.000056  0.000061  0.000070  0.000042
F       0.000056  0.000211  0.000086  0.000117  0.000046
GE      0.000061  0.000086  0.000134  0.000089  0.000043
TSLA    0.000070  0.000117  0.000089  0.000707  0.000051
WMT     0.000042  0.000046  0.000043  0.000051  0.000129
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, considering you have the following setup

#### `Setup`

```
z = io.StringIO("""
ticker     CNP         F        GE      TSLA       WMT                                                  
CNP     1.000000  0.302712  0.408604  0.205812  0.289421
F       0.302712  1.000000  0.510077  0.302415  0.280815
GE      0.408604  0.510077  1.000000  0.288827  0.326106
TSLA    0.205812  0.302415  0.288827  1.000000  0.166978
WMT     0.289421  0.280815  0.326106  0.166978  1.000000""")

df = pd.read_table(z, delim_whitespace=True)

z2= io.StringIO("""
ticker vol
CNP       0.012789
F         0.014525
GE        0.011579
TSLA      0.026573
WMT       0.011369""")

df2 = pd.read_table(z2, delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can `stack` the values, and use `map` to retrieve vol values. Then just multiply through

So first `stack`

```
df = df.set_index('ticker').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['ticker', 'other', 'corr']
```

Such that you get

```
   ticker other      corr
0     CNP   CNP  1.000000
1     CNP     F  0.302712
2     CNP    GE  0.408604
3     CNP  TSLA  0.205812
4     CNP   WMT  0.289421
5       F   CNP  0.302712
6       F     F  1.000000
7       F    GE  0.510077
8       F  TSLA  0.302415
9       F   WMT  0.280815
```

Then filter out equal values (they do not matter)

```
df = df[df.ticker != df.other]
```

And `map`

```
df2 = df2.set_index('ticker')
df['cov'] = df.ticker.map(df2.vol) * df.other.map(df2.vol) * df['corr']
```

Which yields

```
df.head()


    ticker  other   corr        cov
1   CNP     F       0.302712    0.000056
2   CNP     GE      0.408604    0.000061
3   CNP     TSLA    0.205812    0.000070
4   CNP     WMT     0.289421    0.000042
5   F       CNP     0.302712    0.000056
```

Of course you can always `pivot_table` to get it like a matrix

```
df.pivot_table(index=['ticker'], columns=['other'], values=['cov'], fill_value=1)


other   CNP         F          GE           TSLA        WMT
ticker                  
CNP     1.000000    0.000056    0.000061    0.000070    0.000042
F       0.000056    1.000000    0.000086    0.000117    0.000046
GE      0.000061    0.000086    1.000000    0.000089    0.000043
TSLA    0.000070    0.000117    0.000089    1.000000    0.000050
WMT     0.000042    0.000046    0.000043    0.000050    1.000000
```

Or use `.values` to get the corresponding `np.array`

```
df.pivot_table(index=['ticker'], columns=['other'], values=['cov'], fill_value=1).values

array([[  1.00000000e+00,   5.62318492e-05,   6.05076457e-05,
          6.99435817e-05,   4.20812754e-05],
       [  5.62318492e-05,   1.00000000e+00,   8.57872875e-05,
          1.16723972e-04,   4.63723078e-05],
       [  6.05076457e-05,   8.57872875e-05,   1.00000000e+00,
          8.88688235e-05,   4.29291322e-05],
       [  6.99435817e-05,   1.16723972e-04,   8.88688235e-05,
          1.00000000e+00,   5.04454626e-05],
       [  4.20812754e-05,   4.63723078e-05,   4.29291322e-05,
          5.04454626e-05,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: The results are correct but the diagonal would need to be the correlation value multiply by itself instead of 1

Comment: @Rich then just ignore `df = df[df.ticker != df.other]` this line :)

Comment: Thank you. Since I don't have the setup you referred I struggle to stack  the 'df_corr' Should I post my problem here or create another question?

Comment: I found the problem ( 2 columns with the same name). That works perfectly. TY

Comment: at this line: ```df['cov'] = df.ticker.map(df2.vol) * df.other.map(df2.vol) * df['corr']``` I get this error: e: No axis named A.N for object type DataFrame. My df looks identical to the example, has an unnamed index and ticker, other, corr columns, my var vector has ticker as an index and var as its values for the map. Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: @ColeMG What is "A.N" ? Is that a column name ? Seems like there's a typo somewhere here (a trailing space missing, or something like that)

Comment: @rafaelc "A.N" is the first item in the df2 table (the var vector), under the indexed column "RIC". My best guess is that it's trying to use the RIC index in df2, but is expecting a numerical index? But then how would the map work?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.set_index('ticker',inplace=True)
df=pd.DataFrame(s.values*s.values[:,None]*df.values)
df.values[[np.arange(len(df))]*2] = 1
df
Out[24]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.000000  0.000056  0.000061  0.000070  0.000042
1  0.000056  1.000000  0.000086  0.000117  0.000046
2  0.000061  0.000086  1.000000  0.000089  0.000043
3  0.000070  0.000117  0.000089  1.000000  0.000050
4  0.000042  0.000046  0.000043  0.000050  1.000000
```

Comment: The results are correct but the diagonal would need to be the correlation value multiply by itself instead of one.